# Overloaded or rewritten str() function in Python

Tags: python, string

Help, I have big data loaded and suddenly my `str()` does not work. It is not callable anymore. I remember at some point I made an assignment like `str = something`, and now I can't even call `str(1)` anymore, resulting in:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Calling `str` results in `''`

So, in this case it is not possible to restart the interpreter, is there still a way to get the old `str()` back so I can write this data to file?

Comment: There's a reference to the original str at `__builtin__.str`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you use python3? Disregard `__builtin__` then, use Bakuriu's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to re-obtain the built-in `str`:

```
str = type("")
```

Or:

```
import builtins   # __builtin__ in python2
str = builtins.str
```

Just to cite two examples.

---

A more "obscure" way to achieve the same effect:

```
del str
```

This may seem wrong, but after removing the `str` variable, when you type `str` it will be searched in the globals and afterwards in the built-ins, hence achieving the same effect as the other solutions:

```
>>> str = 1
>>> del str
>>> str(127)
'127'
```

In fact this is the *only* way to *completely* revert the previous assignment. If you re-assign the `str` to its original value you are still using a local/global variable instead of a variable used from the built-ins scope. However I cannot think of a situation where this would matter(except that it might *increase* the perfomance when assigning to a local variable).

Comment: @Dualinity I know python pretty well, so this wasn't anything new for me. If you know that python first looks up locals, then globals, then built-ins it's pretty easy to figure out how to revert an assignment like yours.

Comment: @wim I called it "obscure" because you might be surprised that right after a `del str` you *can* use `str`, but it's actually pretty obvious: How to revert an assignment? -> `del` does is meant to do exactly that, and it correctly handles this particular cases as well, reverting the assignment the user made, but not removing the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it call.

```
__builtin__.str
```

That should give you the original str command back.

Comment: Or `str = __builtin__.str` if you want to fix your mistake.

Comment: @Dualinity _ _ thats two underscores.